# Get json data in custom format

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am struggling to format my json data. I want it to look like this. I have looked all over stackoverflow and the the internet and cant find a function that works. Every function I used resulted in unchanged format of the original json data.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Kenneth Auchenberg",
        "avatar": "http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jon Froda",
        "avatar": "http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Anders Pollas",
        "avatar": "http://cdn0.4dots.com/i/customavatars/avatar7112_1.gif",
        "type": "contact"
    },

]
```

However, it keeps printing like this:

```
{"id":"4","name":"Kenneth Auchenberg"}
```

I have tried all of the functions online but to no avail. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "root";
$mysql_database = "students";

$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");



$sql_in= mysql_query("SELECT name,id FROM users order by name desc");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_in))
{
$name=$row['name'];
$id=$row['id'];


$variable = array( 'id' => "$id", 
                       'name' => "$name" );

}
$json = json_encode($variable);

    echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: Try changing like this `$variable[] = array( 'id' => "$id",'name' => "$name" );`

Comment: Also, note that. in json, spaces and newlines between fields don't count.

Comment: it made a bit better but it still prints out in the inline format. Any other ideas?

Comment: @AMADANONInc. what do you mean by that? sorry im a rookie to php/json

Comment: inline format? If you have changed the code as stated above / below you would have got the expected output. Still facing difficulties ? If so, of what type ?

Comment: [{"id":"1","name":"Kenneth Auchenberg"}]   --prints out like this

Comment: @user3747201 after getting inline output just use below mentioned website to convert formatted json output

Comment: if you are using google chrome, you can use `JSONview` extension.

Answer (score 0):

You are just overwriting your `$variable` value with each loop iteration.  This is simple change.  Just make sure you are placing the array created in the loop into a new array position in `$variable` like this:

```
$variable[] = array(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it may help you

```
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_in))
        {
        $name=$row['name'];
        $id=$row['id'];


   $variable[] = array( 'id' => "$id",'name' => "$name" );//use $variable[] instead of $variable

        }
    echo $json = json_encode($variable);
```

Comment: What is different answer from @Mike Brant?

Comment: my apologizes, i din't see that before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the $variable outside the body of while like this

```
$variable = array();
$sql_in= mysql_query("SELECT name,id FROM users order by name desc");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_in))
{
    $name=$row['name'];
    $id=$row['id'];
    $variable[] = array( 'id' => "$id", 'name' => "$name" );
}
```